# Extension of linear functional from C to L1

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I got stuck on this problem that I'm working with:

Let $g \in C[0,1]$ s.t for all $f \in C[0,1]$ we have:
$$ \left| \int_0^1 f(x^2)g(x)dx \right| \leq  \int_0^1 |f(x) |dx  $$
Show that $|g(x)| \leq 2x, x \in [0,1]$.

My attempt: Since the functional (call it $T$) is bounded in $L^1$-norm and $C[0,1]$ is dense in $L^1$ the functional can be extended uniquely to all of $L^1$ with the same bound: $ |\widetilde{T}(f)| \leq \lVert f \rVert_1, \forall f \in L^1$. Then by Riesz representation theorem there is a unique function $\psi \in L^{\infty}$ such that $\widetilde{T}(f)=\int_0^1f(x) \psi(x)dx \ \ \forall f \in L^1$.

After this I'm not sure how to proceed (or if this is the right way to go). Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Hint 1: use substitution $t=x^2$. Then you get your formula for $\psi$. Note that $L_\infty$ norm of $\psi$ equals the norm of $T$.

Comment: I get something like $\psi(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}g(\sqrt{x})$, does it look right? How can I proceed from here?

Comment: Show that $\Vert T\Vert\leq 1$ and use hints from my first comment